# Odoo 14.00 online sign sale order method override

Tags: odoo, digital-signature

I need to override functionality of online Sign sale order in Odoo 14.00 Enterprise.
I don't want customers to confirm sales( the method has lot of other custom functionalities and automation added)  just change my custom state to inform salesperson.

What method is triggered when customer clicks sign button or which module does this process in Odoo ?

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to focus on the **sale_sign** module, which manages the online signature process for quotations and sales orders.

Here's a high-level approach to achieving your requirements:

1. **Identify the Method:** In the sale_sign module, look for the method that handles the signature confirmation.
2. **Override the Method:** Create a custom module that inherits from the sale_sign module. In this module, override the method identified in step 1.

it will be something like this :

```
from odoo import models

class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    def action_your_custom_method(self):
        # logic to change custom state
        self.update({'custom_state': 'your_custom_value'})
```

3. **Test Your Changes:** Make sure your customization works as intended
   without affecting other functionalities.

This approach allows you to modify the sales order process according to your requirements without directly confirming the order upon the customer's signature.